# How to call Development Settings activity in gingerbread?

Tags: android, settings

I want to call that screen where I can enable/disable mock location option on android,
I'm using `Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS`, this works perfectly in some latest version of android but it doesn't works in gingerbread.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try below

com.android.settings.APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS instead of Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS

Please look into below URL link

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/K-PTfqwtE8g

Comment: Thank you, but it doens't work when I make this call
intent.setAction(android.settings.APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS);

Answer (score 0):

I Hope it will helpful.

I checked in Nougat to open all application settings pragmatically using below line of code.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS));
```

Thanks,
Murali.